# jQuery Ajax call wit ajaxForm "Cannot read property 'success' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple php script that echo's a string response.

I am doing a form submit that triggers this script. Now my goal is to show the response of my php script via an Ajax call. But in my console I keep getting:

> jquery.form.js:171 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'success'
>   of undefined

My script (upload.php):

```
<?php
$uploadDirectory = "uploads/";
$uploadFile = $uploadDirectory . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$fileType = pathinfo($uploadFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if file is a pdf
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if($fileType == "pdf") {
        echo "File is a pdf.";
    } else {
        echo "File is not a pdf.";
    }
}
```

My form (index.php):

```
<form action="upload.php" id="uploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select pdf to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload pdf" name="submit">
</form>
```

my ajax call (main.js):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#uploadForm').submit(function() {
        $(this).ajaxForm({
            type: 'post',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(resp);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, anyone could help me out?

Comment: You have not defined any event before calling the success function. Try using $('#uploadForm').submit(function()

Comment: @RajanBenipuri I am sorry but I don't understand your suggestion, why would I use `.submit` when I use `.ajaxForm`?

Comment: can you show `update.php` code

Comment: @PankajMakwana I updated OP with `upload.php` code

Comment: Sounds like an error within the plugin itself, care to provide a link to the source?

Comment: @KevinB https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/4.2.2/jquery.form.js

Comment: wait... it's saying `$.ajaxSettings` is undefined... What does `console.log($.fn.jquery)` give you? Does it change if you use it inside the document.ready vs outside of it?

Answer (score -1):

Please go through the [Jquery Form Plugin API documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#api)

> ajaxForm
>
> Prepares a form to be submitted via AJAX by adding all of the necessary event listeners. It does not submit the form. Use ajaxForm in your document's ready function to prepare your form(s) for AJAX submission. ajaxForm takes zero or one argument. The single argument can be either a callback function or an Options Object.
> Chainable: Yes.

Comment: I've wrapped my `.ajaxForm` in a `$('#uploadForm').submit(function() {` but my page refreshes

Comment: Either you are confused or I am confused. You said you've wrapped your .ajaxForm in $('#uploadForm').submit(function() { but I can't see that wrapping anywhere on your code.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need to use any plugins. You can use jquery post.
This should be your implementation in index.php

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

This is inside your main.js:

```
$(function(){    
    $.post($('#uploadForm'), function(response){
        alert("Response From Server: " + response);
    });
})
```

You can refer jQuery POST documentation here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: $.post is not a function

Comment: I think you are using the wrong version of jquery. Try adding this line before the script. `<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I am using that jQuery version

Comment: Are you refering jquery before your main.js or after?

Comment: I am refering main.js after jQuery